# linking flask static files by URL_STATIC

Tags: python, flask

SO i was creating flask project but while working on index.html I wasn't able to access css,javascript etc files from static folder even after static_url
here is the code

```
<title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Google fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename ='css/styles.css  ')}}" rel="stylesheet">        
</head>
```

wasn't able to access css files after using url_for('static', filename='path/to/file')

Comment: You have some extra spaces on the filename.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I make it work:

```
href="{{ url_for('static', filename='filename.css') }}"
```

the css file is in the folder "static" in the same directory as the html file.